# confused what the "super" keyword is doing in this context

Tags: java, super

I am still trying to learn java, so correct me if I'm wrong. 
As I understand it, the super keyword calls the constructor of a class.  So I do not understand what the significance of saying

```
super.paint(g)
```

does for example, or more recently while reading about animation I came across

```
super.addNotify()
```

I tried looking up documentation on the two (perhaps poorly) and it didn't satisfy my curiosity adequately, so here we are.

Any clarification on those two example or in general would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`super` is a keyword that is a reference to the superclass of the class from which you are using the keyword.

So `super()` calls the constructor of the superclass, `super(x)` calls a parameterised constructor, and `super.paint(g)` calls the `paint()` method of the superclass.

Answer (score 4):

No, the super keyword refers to the base class. So super.f() calls the f() method of the superclass.

In some cases, the superclass privides some basic routines, and when you override the function, you first call the base class's implementation, and then add your custom code. It's the case for both your examples.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of terminological knowledge, but which class would be considered "the base" or "super" class?

Comment: @Sam: The one you inherited from. `class A extends B` => `B`is the superclass or base class of `A`. Have you read ***any*** java books?

Comment: Be nice Armen. @Sam, a good book for Java terminology and best practices is "Effective Java" by Josh Bloch

Comment: @Tim: Was I rude? I am just surprised that one has never come across the terms superclass or base class.

Comment: I've read bits and pieces, and I understand in the context of "a and b,"  it just didn't click when thinking of the superclass of paint and addNotify.  But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Let me describe it in code:

```
public class Parent{

    protected void doSomething(){
       ...
    }
}

//notice the extends Parent which is the super
public class Child extends Parent{ 

    public void doSomethingOnParent(){
       super.doSomething(); //calls a method on the parent class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class A {


public void pirintStr(){

System.out.print("Hello from A");
}

}

public class B extends A{

public void fun(){
 // if you wirte this
printStr(); //this will print Hello from B
//if you want the super class version of this method you can write super keyword 
super.printStr();//this will print Hello from A
}

public void printStr(){
System.out.print("Hello from B");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers are pretty clear. But maybe you would like to know why in the first place someone would call super.

Java have an inheritance system, by whom you may derive a class from another, i.e. take the behaviuor and data structures from a class and reuse it in another. The key here is (or was, when it was conceived) is to reuse code you have already written, and extend it in some way.